# How can I take a value from a span html in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, filter

Hello gangs I have a bit problem I have span links in my html file and I need create  a filter that when I click in a span  this span send a  value in my vue file and  this value turn on a filter.How I can do this?

Actually I take information   for fill the span value from a local array

```
<a class="badge badge-pill badge-white-soft  mr-1 mb-1"href="#"
            data-toggle="pill"
            data-target="#portfolio"
            v-for="country in countries" v-bind:key="country " v-onclick="getvalue"
          >
            <span class="h6 text-uppercase">{{ country}}</span>
          </a>  

 data(){ countries:["Africa","America","Asia","Europe"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you have an error in your syntax, it should be `v-on:click` not `v-onclick`. Also if that continues to not work, the capture modifier, `v-on:click.capture`, may be necessary since you're trying to operate on a inner element of the div.

As for dynamic values for your span, you most likely want to use `v-model`. For more information on binding data to your components, refer to the [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) documentation here. Also, refer to this [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) for additional information regarding event handling.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass the country value to the function? That will be the clean way.

```
<a class="badge badge-pill badge-white-soft  mr-1 mb-1"
   href="#"
   data-toggle="pill"
   data-target="#portfolio"
   v-for="country in countries" v-bind:key="country " v-on:click="getvalue(country)"
   >
   <span class="h6 text-uppercase">{{ country}}</span>
</a>  
...

methods: {
  ...
  getValue(v){
    console.log(v)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send the `country` value on clicking the `a` tag.

```
<a class="badge badge-pill 
     badge-white-soft  mr-1 mb-1"href="#" data-toggle="pill"
     data-target="#portfolio"
     v-for="country in countries" v-bind:key="country " 
     @click="getvalue(country)">
            <span class="h6 text-uppercase">{{ country}}</span>
</a>
```

Inside the method, you will able to console it

```
getValue(country){
  console.log(country)
}
```

You can also use the `span` for click by removing it from `a` tag and

`<span class="h6 text-uppercase" @click="getvalue(country)">{{ country}}`